# D3.js nesting and rollup at same time

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I am looking to convert a csv file into a particular JSON format for a D3.js visualization.  The basic idea is to simultaneously nest and rollup at each level.  In other words, parents at every level in the structure would contain the sum of their children.

An example csv file is the following:

```
Country,State,City,Population,
"USA","California","Los Angeles",18500000,
"USA","California","San Diego",1356000,
"USA","California","San Francisco",837442,
"USA","Texas","Austin",885400,
"USA","Texas","Dallas",1258000,
"USA","Texas","Houston",2196000
```

The JSON format that I am hoping to create is as follows:

```
[
  {
    key: "USA",
    Population: 25032842,
    values: [
      {
        key: "California",
        Population: 20693442,
        values: [
          {
            key: "Los Angeles",
            Population: 18500000
          },
          {
            key: "San Diego",
            Population: 1356000
          },
          {
            key: "San Francisco",
            Population: 837442
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        key: "Texas",
        Population: 4339400,
        values: [
          {
            key: "Austin",
            Population: 885400
          },
          {
            key: "Dallas",
            Population: 1258000
          },
          {
            key: "Houston",
            Population: 2196000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: The d3.nest() function creates a similar structure, but does not aggregate at the parent levels.  On the other hand, the d3.rollup() function will aggregate at the parent levels, but drop all of the children information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: This will only work for D3 **v3**. Things have changed slightly with the new version 4, which requires a little adjustment when accessing the rollup's return value. This is covered by [*"D3.js nesting and rollup at the same time in v4"*](/q/40878072).

---

D3 has no built-in function to do what you are looking for. Using `nest.rollup()` will prune all child nodes to replace them with this function's return value. However, writing a small helper function this can easily be done in two steps:

1. Prepare the nested data structure using `d3.nest()`:

   ```
   var nested = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
     .key(function(d) { return d.State; })
     .rollup(function(cities) {
       return cities.map(function(c) {
         return {"City": c.City, "Population": +c.Population };
       });
     })
     .entries(data);
   ```
2. Loop through all top level nodes to recursively calculate the sums
   of all children.

   ```
   // Recursively sum up children's values
   function sumChildren(node) {
     node.Population = node.values.reduce(function(r, v) {
       return r + (v.values ? sumChildren(v) : v.Population);
     },0);
     return node.Population;
   }

   // Loop through all top level nodes in nested data,
   // i.e. for all countries.
   nested.forEach(function(node) {
     sumChildren(node);
   });
   ```

This will give you exactely the desired output. Have a look at the following snippet to see it in action.

```js
// Initialization
var csv = 'Country,State,City,Population\n' + 
'"USA","California","Los Angeles",18500000\n' + 
'"USA","California","San Diego",1356000\n' + 
'"USA","California","San Francisco",837442\n' + 
'"USA","Texas","Austin",885400\n' + 
'"USA","Texas","Dallas",1258000\n' + 
'"USA","Texas","Houston",2196000\n';

var data = d3.csv.parse(csv);

// Nesting the input using d3.nest()
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.State; })
  .rollup(function(cities) {
    return cities.map(function(c) {
      return {"City": c.City, "Population": +c.Population };
    });
  })
  .entries(data);

// Recursively sum up children's values
function sumChildren(node) {
  node.Population = node.values.reduce(function(r, v) {
    return r + (v.values ? sumChildren(v) : v.Population);
  },0);
  return node.Population;
}

// Loop through all top level nodes in nested data,
// i.e. for all countries.
nested.forEach(function(node) {
  sumChildren(node);
});

// Output. Nothing of interest below this line.
d3.select("body").append("div")
  .style("font-family", "monospace")
  .style("white-space", "pre")
  .text(JSON.stringify(nested,null,2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is a fantastic solution.